# Render Gif from Buffer with Angular 5 / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a backend which returns me following data:

```
"GifUrl":"http://ljdchost.com/AG19Vqv.gif",
"Gif":{
    "type":"Buffer",
    "data":[102,64,0,34,16,...,59]
    }
```

The data in the `"Gif"`-part is returned after I call the `GifUrl`.

I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/omggif) library which can create a gif out of this. The examples use node's `fs` (e.g `fs.writeFileSync`) to create physical files but I don't have access to this part of node within Angular. Creating a file somewhere on the files-system is not my preferred solution anyway.

I would prefer to create the gif on the fly with the given buffer data. So is there a way to do this in Angular/Javascript? My knowledge about HTML and Javascript is not that deep.

Another solution I would go for is to create a tmp-gif-file somewhere in the browser storage but I have no clue if and how that's possible.

Ps: I know that with the omggif-library I could create the gif on the server-side and fetch it with another html-call but my approach for this project is to do as much client-side as possible.

Comment: It's either a buffer or raw RGB values OR a buffer encoded with GIF encoding. Which is it?

Comment: I edited the question with sample data. No clue what exactly it is but I get it if I do a http-call to the `GifUrl`.

Comment: You have the url to the gif, why don't you just crate an img tag and display it directly? Btw, it's an animated gif.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and I now have a gif displayed if I'm online but for offline functionality this is not a solution. I'm also dependent on the reliability of these services (there are multiple hosts). That's why my initial intention was to store the gif-data in a DB and create them on demand.

Comment: Btw I haven't investigated your hint about the animated gif yet. Will do that later this week...